# Eclipse search result, how to show method name

Tags: java, eclipse, search

When I file search for certain keyword with `CTRL + H` in eclipse, results shows the matching line and filename. However, it doesn't show the method name in which the match occurred, and it is slow to double click the result and jump to the beginning of method, when searching a set of particular methods in mind.

Is it possible to format the results as such, that method name is associated with each match?

Comment: Which tab of the Search dialog are you selecting? 'File Search' doesn't show methods because it doesn't know anything about the contents of the files it searches.

Answer (score 0):

As @greg-449 mentioned in the comments, Eclipse's simple file/text search isn't aware of Java constructs like classes and methods. For that you'd need to use Java Search.

Alternatively, you might be interested in [STS Quick Search](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/eclipse-quick-search/), which can be installed into any Eclipse (even if you aren't using STS or Spring). It provides a very useful global workspace text search that shows previews of the context of each match as you select it.